# HTML5 form is not sending

Tags: javascript, php, html, contact-form

I am trying to send a mail with a contact form and php. Unfortunately it is not sending. A little javascript hides the contact form and displays a message, unfortunately it's just stuck at loading

My HTML

```
 <form id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="form.php">
          <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" name="contact-name" placeholder="Name">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" name="contact-email" placeholder="Email">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-subject" name="contact-subject" placeholder="Subject">
                <input id="human" type="text" class="form-control" name="human" placeholder="1+3=?">
          </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" id="contact-message" name="contact-message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send" formaction="form.php">
          </div>
          </form>
```

**Edit:** My PHP

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['contact-name'];
$email = $_POST['contact-email'];
$message = $_POST['contact-message'];
$from = $_POST['contact-email'];
$to = 'mail@domain.com'; // insert your Mail here
$subject = 'Hello';
$human = $_POST['human'];
$resp = null;
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

if ($human == '4') { // edit the number 4 if you want anoter anti spam question          
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        $resp = array(
            "status" => "OK",
            "msg" => "Thanks! We will reply shortly."
        );
    } else {
        $resp = array(
            "status" => "ERROR",
            "msg" => "Something went wrong, go back and try again"
        );
    }
} else if ($human != '4') {
    $resp = array(
        "status" => "ERROR",
        "msg" => "Wrong antispam answer!"
    );
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
print json_encode($resp);
?>
```

This is the JS for hiding the form

```
$.fn.formAlert = function (resp) {
if (resp && resp.msg) {
  this.html(resp.msg);
}

if (resp && resp.status) {
  if (resp.status === 'OK') {
    this.attr('class', 'alert alert-success');
  } else {
    this.attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
  }
} else {
  this.attr('class', 'hidden');
}
};
```

**EDIT:** And this is the snipped for the submit

```
 $('#contact-form').submit(function (e) {
  var $this = $(this),
    url = $this.attr('action');

  e.preventDefault();

  //disable any further form interaction
  $this
    .find(':input')
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    .filter('[type=submit]') //get the submit button
      .hide() //hide it
      .after('<div class="loader"></div>'); //add a loader after it

  $.post(url, {
    data: $this.serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (resp) {
      $('#contact-form-msg').formAlert(resp);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

I really have no idea what I am missing here :( - any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: where is start of <form in HTML?

Comment: @Sidstar sorry, just edited it right now!

Comment: your fields are named "contact-name" try $_POST['contact-name'] instead of $_POST['name'];

Comment: where have you assigned `formAlert`?

Comment: also can you post your code for the form submit part? could give a better insight to your problem

Comment: just look at the field names first as stated in my answer and see if that resolves the situation.

Comment: @anurupr updated, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) $.serialize only serializes [successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2), thus not disabled controls.

Actually your form IS posted, just empty.

Simply invert disabling and posting in your code:

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function (e) {
  var $this = $(this),
    url = $this.attr('action');

  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax( { url: url,
    data: $this.serialize(), type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (resp) { console.log(resp);
      $('#contact-form-msg').formAlert(resp); 
    }
  });

  //disable any further form interaction
  $this
    .find(':input')
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    .filter('[type=submit]') //get the submit button
      .hide() //hide it
      .after('<div class="loader"></div>'); //add a loader after it
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Just did that, no changes at all :(

Comment: You mixed `$.post` and `$.ajax` syntaxes too, corrected my answer

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not working (resp is null, but I don't know why)

Comment: How do you test, what's your browser ?

Comment: You test if `submit` is set in your form, when the submit button is NOT a [successful control](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2): remove the test on `isset($_POST['submit'])`, why did you test it anyway >

Comment: Just updated the php code (initial post) and it looks like it runs now :D thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$name = $_POST['contact-name'];
$email = $_POST['contact-email'];
$message = $_POST['contact-message'];
$from = $_POST['contact-email'];
```

instead of:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = $_POST['email'];
```

---

Comment: not working ok but I am sure situation has moved a little bit. Do you get any PHP error/warning? or what does resp["msg"] tells you now?

Comment: the JS code you have posted in question is for receiving the response from PHP... where is the JS code / AJAX query that sends the form to PHP?

Answer (score -1):

Just before the first div
Add

That should work.

form method="post"

Comment: its already there... if you look closely field names called in PHP are incorrect.